# Problem loading nkarta font

Tags: fonts, symbols, miktex

I've been following the instructions on this [reference](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) page 191 to add the 113th symbol in my document. So I've installed the nkarta package via the `MikTeX` console, everything went well, then applied the instructions of the symbols reference, but I get a "q" instead of the scales symbol I want.
In fact I added `nkarta.mf` in the 'font' field as in:

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{nkarta}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{nkarta}{m}{n}{<-> nkarta15.mf}{}
```

but the nkarta package has several others. I don't know which one to choose:

[image]

I'm running `pdflatex`, with no error. I don't understand.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, simple error of mine. I sorted it out.
The `\Pisymbol{nkarta}{113}` must not be in math mode. If so, it apparently calls another symbol (a q letter...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Good that you solved your own problem. Next time however, it would be good if you provide code of a small but complete example document that shows what you tried to do - in this case using the symbol in math mode. With such a complete document other people could spot the mistake, and point it out to you in case you didn't find it yourself.